# gzserver: error while loading shared libraries: libdart-collision-bullet.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't even know how did this happen. One day, I just open the laptop and start to work. Suddenly, it's not working anymore.

I can't even run turtlebot3. I reinstalled foxy and gazebo11. No luck. It just...out of blue not working again.

killall gzserver/killall gzclient/ pkill doesn't help at all. ANy idea? I really want to use gazebo again

error

```
gzserver: error while loading shared libraries: libdart-collision-bullet.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

even i reinstall gazebo11, this happens still.

```
bwuk@robots:~$ cd /usr/local/bin/gazebo
bash: cd: /usr/local/bin/gazebo: No such file or directory
bwuk@robots:~$
```

I still have .model though

```
bwuk@robots:~$ cd .gazebo/models/
bwuk@robots:~/.gazebo/models$
```

Everytime I load gazebo from launch, it simply frozen, crashed or says directory doesn't exist.

How did this happen?

I even echo path, but it just don't show any result

```
bwuk@robots:~$ echo $GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH

bwuk@robots:~$ echo $GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH

bwuk@robots:~$
```

I'm using foxy, gazebo11 and ubuntu 20.04

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/385317/gzserver:-error-while-loading-shared-libraries:-libdart-collision-bullet.so.6:-cannot-open-shared-object-file:-no-such-file-or-directory/) by [kak13](https://answers.ros.org/users/71412/kak13/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2021-08-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solution:

- `sudo apt remove --purge libdart*`
- Remove `dartsim/ppa` in Software &  Updates -> Other Software
- sudo apt update
- sudo apt install libdart-dev
- sudo apt install libdart-all-dev (only if above installs)
- But if this failed due to `unable to fetch some archives`, run this
  `sudo apt update --fix-missing && sudo apt install libdart-all-dev`
- Install gazebo `curl -sSL http://get.gazebosim.org | sh`
- `gazebo` (to check if it works now)

If you still getting error after attempt to load gazebo from launch in ros2, then follow this;

`. /usr/share/gazebo/setup.sh` inside your workspace.

Source:

- ROS answer: [link](https://answers.ros.org/question/358847/cannot-launch-gzclient-on-a-launch-file-results-in-shared_ptr-assertion-error/)
- `rajput`username on stackoverflow on `Gazebo 11 does not run` question page

---

Originally posted by [kak13](https://answers.ros.org/users/71412/kak13/) with karma: 113 on 2021-08-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-08-30**:
Please do not post link-only answers, especially not when those links lead to 3rd party sites (ie: not on `ros.org` or ROS related Github pages): the links go stale pretty quickly.

Please summarise how you solved your problem here in your answer.

**Comment by [kak13](https://answers.ros.org/users/71412/kak13/) on 2021-08-30**:
Right, my bad! Let me fix this then